# "Submodel" data not loading in Table control of SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, xml, sapui5

### Environement

Framework : SAPUI5 V.1.38.39
Control used : [Table](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Table)
IDE : SAP Web IDE

### Issue

The data-bound to the control are or empty or the ones of the oData model instead of the oData "submodel"

### Code

Definition of the Master model in the manifest.json:

```
"sap.app": {
    [...]
    "dataSources": {
        "ZTRACK_AND_TRACE_SRV": {
            "uri": "/sap/opu/odata/sap/ZTRACK_AND_TRACE_SRV",
            "type": "OData",
            "settings": {
                "odataVersion": "2.0",
                "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml",
                "annotations": []
            }
        }
    }
},
[...]
"sap.ui5": {
    [...]
    "models": {
        "TrackAndTrace": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel",
            "settings": {
                "defaultOperationMode": "Auto",
                "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
                "defaultCountMode": "None"
            },
            "dataSource": "ZTRACK_AND_TRACE_SRV",
            "preload": true
        },
        "HandlingUnitMultipleModel": {
            "type": "sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel",
            "settings": {
                "defaultOperationMode": "Auto",
                "defaultBindingMode": "OneWay",
                "defaultCountMode": "None"
            },
            "dataSource": "ZTRACK_AND_TRACE_SRV",
            "preload": true
        },
    [...]
}
```

Creation of oData model in the controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
    [...]
    "TrackAndTrace/ztntapp_b2b/model/models"
], function ([...], models) {
    "use strict";

    return BaseController.extend("TrackAndTrace.controller.DirectTrackView", {
        formatter: formatter,
        onInit: function () {

            var sSendingId = window.URI()._parts.fragment.split("/")[2] ? window.URI()._parts.fragment.split("/")[2] : "";
            var sWaybill = window.URI()._parts.fragment.split("/")[3] ? window.URI()._parts.fragment.split("/")[3] : "";
            var sZip = window.URI()._parts.fragment.split("/")[4] ? window.URI()._parts.fragment.split("/")[4] : "";
            this.initODataModel();

            this.getView().setModel(models.createHandlingUnit(this.oTrackNTraceModel, sSendingId, sWaybill, sZip), "HandlingUnitModel"); 
            // this.oTrackNTraceModel is the model from the manifest
            [...]
        },
    [...]
```

How is define the HandlingUnitModel in model.js :

```
createHandlingUnit: function (oModel, sSendingId, sWaybill, sZip) {
            var HandlingUnitModel = new JSONModel();
            oModel.read(`/HANDLING_UNITSet(SendingId='${sSendingId}',Waybill='${sWaybill}',Zip='${sZip}')`, {
                success: function (oData) {
                    HandlingUnitModel.setData(oData.results ? oData.results[0] : oData);
                }
            });
            return HandlingUnitModel;
},
```

And finally on the view on the try 1 :

```
<Table inset="false" items="{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails'}" id="tableStatusDetails">
    <columns>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="15%">
            <Text text="{i18n>date}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="15%">
            <Text text="{i18n>time}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="40%">
            <Text text="{i18n>state}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="30%">
                <Text text="{i18n>city}" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{path:'HandlingUnitModel>/StateTimestamp',type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date'}"/>
                <Text text="{path:'HandlingUnitModel>/StateTimestamp',formatter:'.formatter.formatStateTime'}"/>
                <Text text="{parts:[{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/EventCategory'},{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/StateId'},{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/StateDescription'}], formatter:'.formatter.noExpectedStatus'}">
                    <customData>
                        <core:CustomData key="EventCategory" value="{HandlingUnitModel>/EventCategory}"/>
                    </customData>
                </Text>
                <Text text="{HandlingUnitModel>/City}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

The try 1 problem is that the bound data are from HandlingUnitModel instead of HandlingUnitModel/toDetails mentioned in the "items" property of the table

on the try 2 :

```
<Table inset="false" items="{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails'}" id="tableStatusDetails">
    <columns>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="15%">
            <Text text="{i18n>date}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="15%">
            <Text text="{i18n>time}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="40%">
            <Text text="{i18n>state}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="30%">
                <Text text="{i18n>city}" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{path:'HandlingUnitModel>StateTimestamp',type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date'}"/>
                <Text text="{path:'HandlingUnitModel>StateTimestamp',formatter:'.formatter.formatStateTime'}"/>
                <Text text="{parts:[{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>EventCategory'},{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>StateId'},{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>StateDescription'}], formatter:'.formatter.noExpectedStatus'}">
                    <customData>
                        <core:CustomData key="EventCategory" value="{HandlingUnitModel>/EventCategory}"/>
                    </customData>
                </Text>
                <Text text="{HandlingUnitModel>City}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

With the try 2 there is no data bound, the table is empty without any error message in the console

on the try 3 :

```
<Table inset="false" items="{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails'}" id="tableStatusDetails">
    <columns>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="15%">
            <Text text="{i18n>date}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="15%">
            <Text text="{i18n>time}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="40%">
            <Text text="{i18n>state}"/>
        </Column>
        <Column minScreenWidth="Tablet" demandPopin="true" width="30%">
                <Text text="{i18n>city}" />
        </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
        <ColumnListItem>
            <cells>
                <Text text="{path:'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails/StateTimestamp',type:'sap.ui.model.type.Date'}"/>
                <Text text="{path:'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails/StateTimestamp',formatter:'.formatter.formatStateTime'}"/>
                <Text text="{parts:[{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails/EventCategory'},{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails/StateId'},{path: 'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails/StateDescription'}], formatter:'.formatter.noExpectedStatus'}">
                    <customData>
                        <core:CustomData key="EventCategory" value="{HandlingUnitModel>/EventCategory}"/>
                    </customData>
                </Text>
                <Text text="{HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails/City}" />
            </cells>
        </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
</Table>
```

With the try 3 the issue is the same than with the try 2

### Hypothesis

I suppose the data from HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails doesn't load but why ? and how to make it happens ?

Comment: Try binding as follows: `{HandlingUnitModel>City}` (without '/' after the '>'). Edit: you are binding the table to the path `'HandlingUnitModel>/toDetails'`, so all bindings inside the table are relative to that path. Relative binding is without '/' after '>' (else  it is binding to the absolute path)

Comment: Off-topic but what is the reason for still using the deprecated `sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel`? Are you getting errors when using `v2.ODataModel`?

Comment: Hello @Lumpenstein this is the try3 of the post :) but yes it should be the correct syntax.

Comment: Hello @BoghyonHoffmann I suppose in sapui5 v1.38.39 i might be not yet deprecated ? i am not sure I think so because in this ui5 version i get not found error for V2.ODataModel

Comment: @SylwekFr The documentation in 1.38 mentions that the [`sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel` is deprecated](https://ui5.sap.com/1.38.39/#docs/guide/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html) and `v2.ODataModel` should be used instead ([Related blog post](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/03/stop-using-sap.ui.model.odata.odatamodel-aka-v1-odatamodel-its-deprecated-since-2014)). Simply remove `"type": "sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel"` from the `manifest.json`. Then, the `v2.ODataModel` should be used. However, you might have to add `useBatch: false` to the `"settings"` if the service doesn't support `$batch`.

Comment: Hello @BoghyonHoffmann thank you for pointing it out, I changed it however it didn't solve the problem and it show the error Component Manifest: Class "sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel.ODataModel" for model "HandlingUnitMultipleModel" could not be loaded. Error: failed to load 'sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel/ODataModel.js' from resources/sap/ui/model/odata/v2/ODataModel/ODataModel.js: 404 - error - ["sap.ui5"]["models"]["HandlingUnitMultipleModel"]